# Using grep function to extract key-value from AWS certificate list

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, grep

Running `$ aws acm list-certificates` on my AWS console lists all the ARN  certificates. Now the answer that i get is in list format. How do i fetch the particular arn from this list using grep cmmnd ?

for example: running this `$ aws acm list-certificates` gives me,

```
[       {"CertificateArn": "ARN1","DomainName": "A1.com"} ,
        {"CertificateArn": "ARN2","DomainName": "A2.com"} ,
        {"CertificateArn": "ARN3","DomainName": "A3.com"} ,
        {"CertificateArn": "ARN4","DomainName": "A4.com"} ,
        {"CertificateArn": "ARN5","DomainName": "A5.com"} 
]
```

now i wanna get CertificateArn associated with "DomainName=A5.com" using grep command. What cmmnd should i use ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--query` for filtering / manipulating AWS cli outputs, see [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side).

In your case this might look like

```
aws acm list-certificates --query "(CertificateSummaryList[?DomainName=='A5.com'].CertificateArn)[0]"
```

Optionally with a `--output=text` to not have `"` around the output.